# Magento Store - Horizontal Items in Grid

Tags: magento

In Magento how do I specify how many products I would like displayed horizontally in the grid.  By default it is 3 and I can't see where to change this (I would like to set it to 2).

Thanks,
Alan.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to find comprehensive instruction for Magento 1.4 with theming changes and local.xml, however there's possibly a bug with the columns in grid view as noted here:

http://www.lotusseedsdesign.com/blog/change-grid-view-column-4-product-listing

I got by with this in local.xml for a one column page/4 column grid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <!-- Other template tweaks here -->
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="content">
      <reference name="category.products">
       <reference name="product_list">
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>4</count></action>
        </reference>
       </reference>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the catalog.xml layout file you can add an 'action' tag inside the product-list block that will set the number of columns... the template (list.phtml) will call it as get[Something], so you want to have the method="set[Something]" in the layout file be the same. The class the methods are being called on is in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php ... I think. catalog.xml has in it some commented out examples of using 'action' for doing paging, so you should be able to copy those. Bit vague...but no code handy to look at.